# Do you always win with higher JP?

Tags: magikarp-jump

In Magikarp Jump, are you guaranteed to win if you have a JP advantage (even a single 1 JP)?  Or is there a random (or not-random) factor that can cause you to lose with a JP advantage?  If so, is there a "safe" percentage and/or amount that guarantees you a win?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on my own tests, JP has a direct relationship to meters jumped; there is no random factor.  So a higher JP, even by 1, will always yield a higher meter value.

The relationship is nonlinear; it approximately is described by a relationship between the square root of meters jumped and the logarithm of Jump Points.  Further research is ongoing to determine if this is the best relationship, and exactly what the coefficients would be for this relationship.

Comment: This matches my tests too. It's easiest to check when going through many matches with a new Magikarp. It will always jump to the same height unless it gets a cheer bonus.

Comment: It's worth noting that a Magikarp with lower JP can still win if a helper Pokémon cheers them on.