# Can Support Pokémon assist with skipped battles?

Tags: magikarp-jump

Support Pokémon can boost a Magikarp's Jump Power 5-25% by cheering. This can allow a Magikarp to win a battle [even if it would otherwise have a lower JP](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/310152/181240).

**Can Support Pokémon boost JP by cheering during skipped battles?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was tracking JP values between battles, it seems that skipped battles use only your magikarp's JP and never included the support pokemon. Every battle I skipped had the same jump height at a given JP, there was no variation. If you are re-advancing through a league that a previous generation started and you get to a battle where the opponent has more JP than your magikarp, you will need to watch the battle instead of skip it in the hopes that a support pokemon will give you a boost to win.
While I do not have hard data or documentation to back me up, I have checked the numbers several times across many different generations, JP amounts, and in different leagues with several support pokemon present in the training pond.

TLDR: Support pokemon do not help with skipped battles.

Comment: While technically anecdotal, this matches my tests as well.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, when you skip a battle it just simulates the battle, including the support Pokémon.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? [Dark Absol's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/312518/181240) to a different question claimed otherwise.

Comment: Unless the extremely unlikely situation of every single skipped battle not receiving a support boost occurred in my game, this answer is incorrect.